# Xargs string interpolation, not by inserting a space

Tags: linux, xargs

I want to repeat

```
touch ../template/filename
```

where `filename` comes from `find`. I want `xargs` to apply the `touch` operation, but I dont want it to **insert a space** like it usually does which derives into:

```
touch ../template/ filename
```

Here is my incomplete command. How Do I complete it?

```
find *.html | xargs touch ../template/WHAT-NOW
```

Answer (score 13):

```
find -name "*.html" | xargs -d"\n" -I"{}" touch ../template/{}

find -name "*.html" -exec touch ../template/{} \;
```

Note that `find *.html` is wrong, since wildcards are expanded *before* command execution.

Comment: The find command gives me `./photos_each.html` when I actually meant `photos_each.html`. I want simply the filename

Comment: @aitchnyu: They are equivalent here.  Both `../template/photos_each.html` and `../template/./photos_each.html` should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is easier to write as a shell loop.  For instance, in C shell you might write:

```
foreach i (`find -name "*.html"`)
   touch ../template/$i
end
```

And here it is in bash:

```
for i in `find -name "*.html"`
do
   touch ../template/$i
done
```

And in my Hamilton C shell (full disclosure: I'm the author), I added a ["..." wildcard](http://hamiltonlabs.com/userguide/31-Wildcarding.htm) to tree-walk, so you could write:

```
foreach i (.../*.html)
   touch ../template/$i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using GNU Parallel instead. That way you avoid nasty surprises if the filenames contain space ' or ":

```
find *.html | parallel -X touch ../template/{/}
```

See the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1